# Create a Final Group of items if at least one Intermediate Group in common exists between two items

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, recursive-query

After to have group the item based on first criteria we obtain this result.

My_table (reference in the SQL script below)

| item | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1,6 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3,5 | 3 |
| 4,5 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7,10,11 | 6 |
| 8,10,11,13 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 12,15,18 | 9 |
| 14 | 10 |
| 14,15,18,20 | 11 |
| 21 | 2 |

This group is an intermediate group.

So, to find the final group, we explode the intermediate group to see what are all the groups to which an element belongs.

And the output intermediate is

| item | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| ... | ... |
| 10 | 6 |
| 10 | 7 |
| 11 | 6 |
| 11 | 7 |
| 12 | 9 |
| 13 | 7 |
| ... | ... |
| 18 | 11 |
| 20 | 11 |
| 21 | 2 |

we have as many lines for an item as it has groups

Below, we must aggregate the item 1 and 6 because they have at least one group in common, the group 1. Then we aggregate item 3, 4, 5 because there have at least one group in common. Same for item 7,8,10,11 and 13. The same again for 14,15,16 and 20. Only item 9 has not common group with each other.
So the second output intermediate expected is to put for each item all its groups like this.

| item | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 3,4 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 10 | 6,7 |
| 11 | 6,7 |
| 12 | 9 |
| 13 | 7 |
| 14 | 10,11 |
| 15 | 9,11 |
| 18 | 9,11 |
| 20 | 11 |
| 21 | 2 |

this will allow us to create a new group in which we will have the items that have similar intermediate groups. This is the expected result

| item | inter_group | final_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3,4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3,4 | 3 |
| 6 | 1,5 | 1 |
| 7 | 6,7 | 7 |
| 8 | 6,7 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 6,7 | 7 |
| 11 | 6,7 | 7 |
| 12 | 9,10,11 | 8 |
| 13 | 6,7 | 7 |
| 14 | 9,10,11 | 8 |
| 15 | 9,10,11 | 8 |
| 18 | 9,10,11 | 8 |
| 20 | 9,10,11 | 8 |
| 21 | 2 | 2 |

Actually, the final group is correct when each item has unique group and that there is no more possible crossing with other groups.

So i've try a recursive function in SQL but it stop at the first step (inter group) :

```
WITH RECURSIVE
T1 AS (
  SELECT  
  item, 
  intermediate_group, 
  FROM my_table, unnest(split(group)) AS item) 

,
  T2 as (
  SELECT item,
  STRING_AGG(CAST(intermediate_group as STRING)) AS intermediate_group
  from T1
  GROUP BY item) 

SELECT DISTINCT item, intermediate_group as final_group
FROM T2
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *, dense_rank() over(order by inter_group) as final_group
from (
  select item, 
    string_agg('' || `group`) as inter_group
  from your_table, unnest(split(item)) item
  group by item
)
# order by final_group
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for you answer. It’s correct to my first edited questions but i’ve modified it because because I was wrong in my question. I would like to group items that have at least one I_group in common and not those that have exactly the same group(s).